# Text won't vertically center properly in canvas with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS, just finished a course.

I have a PHP (using GD library) web app, which works well, but I want to recreate it with JS (without jQuery). The app generates a 512 x 512 image from text based on user input. Only 1-3 letters and/or numbers can be added, so I don't have a bunch of text that needs wrapping or stuff like that.

After reading various forum posts and tutorials, I'm still stuck at making the text vertically center in the canvas.

This is the canvas HTML code:

```
<canvas class="border" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
```

This is the final JS code so far, which *almost* works:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const inputText = document.querySelector('#inputText');
const selectFont = document.querySelector('#selectFont');
const inputFontSize = document.querySelector('#inputFontSize');
const inputBgColor = document.querySelector('#inputBgColor');
const inputTextColor = document.querySelector('#inputTextColor');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

fontFamilies = [
    new FontFace ('Roboto', 'url(/assets/fonts/roboto-v20-latin-700.woff2)'),
    new FontFace ('Merriweather', 'url(/assets/fonts/merriweather-v22-latin-900.woff2)'),
    new FontFace ('Dancing Script', 'url(/assets/fonts/dancing-script-v15-latin-700.woff2)')
];

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();    

    const getText = inputText.value.trim();
        
    // const textWidth = context.measureText(getText).width;    

    context.fillStyle = inputBgColor.value; 
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 512, 512);     
    context.fillStyle = inputTextColor.value;

    context.textBaseline = 'middle'; 
    context.textAlign = 'center';     

    fontFamilies.forEach(fontFamily => {

        fontFamily.load().then(font => {

            document.fonts.add(font);
    
            if (selectFont.value === 'roboto') {
                context.font = inputFontSize.value + 'px' + ' ' + 'Roboto';
            } else if (selectFont.value === 'merriweather') {
                context.font = inputFontSize.value + 'px' + ' ' + 'Merriweather';
            } else if (selectFont.value === 'dancingScript') {
                context.font = inputFontSize.value + 'px' + ' ' + 'Dancing Script';
            }
            
            context.fillText(getText, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 512);
            
        });
    });     
});
```

This is the end result:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom margin is clearly bigger.

I also:

- Used different font families, including system ones;
- Used both .ttf and .woff2 formats;
- Switched browsers.

Comment: Setting the context's textBaseline attribute to "middle" sets it to the middle of the font's 'em square', not to the vertical midpoint of the current text. The em square value has to accommodate the heights of all the letters in the font, including letters with descenders (f, q, p, etc)

Comment: Thanks! I checked out "em square", and it definitely makes sense now. If you're aware of any way to handle this, or an alternative way, please let me know.